# Playwright fails to test disabled elements under shadowroot(open)

Tags: playwright, stenciljs

I'm building a custom `button` component using `stencil` and testing it with `playwright`. The weird part is that the test passes during debug and fails on a real test. This is how the `html` is rendered in the dom:

```
<my-button disabled="true" class="hydrated">Action
    #shadow-root(open)
    <button disabled=""><slot></slot></button>
</my-button>
```

The relevant parts of the component:

```
export class Button {
  @Prop() disabled: boolean = false;
.
.
.
render() {
    return (
      <button
        disabled={this.disabled}
          <slot></slot>
      </button>
    );
  }
```

The playwright test:

```
test('button disables', async ({ page }) => {
    const mbutton = page.locator("my-button");
    const button = page.locator("my-button >> button");
    await mbutton.evaluate(async el => {
        await el.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    });
    await expect(await button.isDisabled()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The error:

```
Error: expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Received: false

  82 |             });
> 83 |             await expect(await button.isDisabled()).toBeTruthy();
     |                                                     ^
  85 |         });
```

Comment: Please file an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) with a repro (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run it locally.